# kubectl run fail in interactive mode on CI

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, kubectl

have issue with

```
kubectl run -ti
```

in gitlab ci.
For testing in CI we run docker container with "npm t" command in interactive mode and it was perfectly work on docker.
After migrate to Kubernetes have issue, as kubectl run give next error: `Unable to use a TTY - input is not a terminal or the right kind of file`
Job run in image: **lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl**
If run kubectl run from local machine all work.
Pls help

Comment: Could you please share here CI code, especially that line where you execute https://hub.docker.com/r/lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl?

Answer (score 1):

The [PodSpec `container:`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#container-v1-core) has a `tty` attribute, which defaults to `false` but which one can set to `true` (that's what the `-t` option, which is a shortcut for `--tty=true`, does in `kubectl exec`). You can experiment with setting `stdin: true` but at your peril, since it can hang the Pod waiting for "someone" to type something.